# Event or hook when user account email validated

Tags: plugin-development, users, emails, activation

Is there an event or hook we can leverage after a user verifies their email address? It looks like this is handled in `UsersController::actionVerifyEmail()` which calls `$this->_onAfterActivateUser` which calls `$this->_redirectUserAfterAccountActivation`. The specific users being created will not have CP access, so they will be redirected to `craft()->config->getLocalized('activateAccountSuccessPath')` in that method.

I would like to be able to set a flash message to confirm the email verification and informing them they need to log in to access all of the site, but I don't see any events or hooks to tie into. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently aren't any verification events, but if the user is in a `pending` state (i.e. they haven't been activated yet), verification will trigger [activation](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/services/UsersService.php#L837), which triggers the [onBeforeActivateUser](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#users-onBeforeActivateUser) and [onActivateUser](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#users-onActivateUser) events.

Comment: onActivateUser should be just what I need, thanks!